# Python - Getting string inside string

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use check_password_hash from Flask, getting a value from my MySQL database. I can fetch the password from my database but when I used, return me a False value. Here is my code:

```
class AuthUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('username', type=str, help= 'Username')
            parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help= 'Password')

            args = parser.parse_args()

            _userUsername = args['username']
            _userPassword = args['password']


            conn = mysql.connect()

            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('gsAuthUser', (_userUsername,))
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.callproc('gsGetPassword', (_userUsername,))
            pwd = cursor.fetchall()
            print(pwd) 

            _userPassDecrypt = check_password_hash(pwd, _userPassword)

            print(_userPassDecrypt) 



        except Exception as e:
            return {'error': str(e)}

         api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')  api.add_resource(AuthUser, '/AuthUser')
```

And here is the output:

```
((u'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$QtDUZdwY$fa7d211dc9e3db9513b7e11096e257272b2edde3af3e2a0d33ca5cba53a942c7',),)
```

I think I just need the value after the sha256: but I can't fetch it.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now! Thanks! 
Here is what I did:

cursor.callproc('gsGetPassword', (_userUsername,))
        pwd_db = cursor.fetchall()

```
    pwd_str = str(pwd_db)  
    pwd = pwd_str.split('(')[2][2:-5] 
    _userPassDecrypt = check_password_hash(pwd, _userPassword)


    if (len(data) > 0):
        if(_userPassDecrypt):
       # if(str(data[0][2]) == _userPassDecrypt):
            return {'StatusCode': '200', 'UserID': str(data[0][0])} 
        else:
            return {'StatusCode': '100', 'Message':'Authentication Failure'}

except Exception as e:
    return {'error': str(e)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but there may be a better way to do this:

```
except Exception as e:
    return {'error': str(e.split(':')[2][:-5])}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is for the check_password_hash?